# Placing a list inside a list of different type Generics in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a method in a C# class which is setting the values of a DTOS of a JSON. I need to place a list of type JiraContent1 with its own values inside of a list of type JiraContent. I am receiving the error 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. In what way can I place one list inside the other without receiving the error message?

```
    public void MakeRequest(string _summary, string _description, Boolean _isurgent)
    {
        var jiraRequest = new JiraRequest
        {
            Fields = new JiraFields
            {
                Summary = _summary,
                Issuetype = new JiraIssuetype
                {
                    Name = "Support-Request"
                },
                Project = new JiraProject
                {
                    Key = "NAV"
                },
                Description = new JiraDescription
                {
                    Type = "doc",
                    Version = 1,
                    Content = new List<JiraContent>().Add(new JiraContent
                    {
                        Type = "paragraph",
                        Content = new List<JiraContent1>().Add(new JiraContent1
                        {
                            Text = _description,
                            Type = "text"
                        })
                    })

                }
            }
        };

        string myJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jiraRequest);
    }
```

Contents of the DTOS

```
public class JiraRequest
{
    public JiraFields Fields { get; set; }
}

public class JiraFields
{
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public JiraIssuetype Issuetype { get; set; }
    public JiraProject Project { get; set; }
    public JiraDescription Description { get; set; }
}

public class JiraIssuetype
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class JiraProject
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class JiraDescription
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public List<JiraContent> Content { get; set; }
}

public class JiraContent
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<JiraContent1> Content { get; set; }
}

public class JiraContent1
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this:

```
Content = new List<JiraContent>().Add(new JiraContent
                {
                    Type = "paragraph",
                    Content = new List<JiraContent1>().Add(new JiraContent1
                    {
                        Text = _description,
                        Type = "text"
                    })
                })
```

Break down these expressions, and the code is attempting to assign the result the of the `.Add()` call, which has no return value. You can try a collection initializer insted:

```
Content = new List<JiraContent> {
                new JiraContent
                {
                    Type = "paragraph",
                    Content = new List<JiraContent1> {
                        new JiraContent1
                        {
                            Text = _description,
                            Type = "text"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I tried this, I am still receiving the same error. I've updated my question with the code in the DTOS if that is any help.

Comment: @GearoidSheehan I missed that `.Add()` was also nested inside the first use. Updated the answer to also remove the inner call.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Content = new List<JiraContent1>
        {
            new JiraContent1{
                Text = _description,
                Type = "text"
            }
        }
```